# AWK Finding a way to print lines containing a word from a comma separated string

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, matching

I want to write a bash script that only prints lines that, on their second column, contain a word from a comma separated string. Example:

```
words="abc;def;ghi;jkl"

>cat log1.txt
hello;abc;1234
house;ab;987
mouse;abcdef;654
```

What I want is to print only lines that contain a whole word from the "words" variable. That means that "ab" won't match, neither will "abcdef". It seems so simple yet after trying for manymany hours, I was unable to find a solution.

For example, I tried this as my awk command, but it matched any substring.

```
-F \; -v b="TSLA;NVDA" 'b ~ $2 { print $0 }'
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

EDIT:

A sample input would look like this

```
1;UNH;buy;344.74
2;PG;sell;138.60
3;MSFT;sell;237.64
4;TSLA;sell;707.03
```

A variable like this would be set

```
filter="PG;TSLA"
```

And according to this filter, I want to echo these lines

```
2;PG;sell;138.60
4;TSLA;sell;707.03
```

Comment: `"abc;def;ghi;jkl"` is a semi-colon separated string, not comma separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
words="abc;def;ghi;jkl"
awk -F';' -v s=";$words;" 'index(s, FS $2 FS)' log1.txt

hello;abc;1234
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain the meaning of `index(s, FS $i FS)`? FS is automatically set by -F ';' to be ';', but doesn't that index command imply, that there should be delimiters on both sides?

Comment: We are splitting each field by `;` when we use `-F';'`. Then in `index` function we are wrapping each field with `;` on both sides i.e. `FS $i FS`. Our variable `s` already has `;` as delimiter and at start/end. This gives us ability to call `index` function for complete matches only.

Answer (score 4):

Grep is a good choice here:

```sh
grep -Fw -f <(tr ';' '\n' <<<"$words") log1.txt
```

With awk I'd do

```sh
awk -F ';' -v w="$words" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(w, a, /;/)
        # next line moves the words into the _index_ of an array, 
        # to make the file processing much easier and more efficient
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) words[a[i]]=1
    }
    $2 in words
' log1.txt
```

Comment: Or with bash `grep -Fwf- <<<"${words//;/$'\n'}" file`

Comment: That grep command would find the word anywhere it appears in a line, not just in the 2nd field, and would produce partial matches if any field contained non-word-constituent characters.

Comment: That awk BEGIN statement can just be `split(w, a); for (i in a) words[a[i]]`.